Uv mapping fix symmetrical mapping
I just started using blender for one of my projects where I need map UV co-ordinates to be able to use that object in three.js
I found similar question here and i tried disabling the sync but that did not solve my problem so i am asking with screenshot here for clarification of my need.

I am manually mapping UV as shown here in this screenshot but as we can see whenever the last vertex is selected and moved, corresponding left most vertex also starts moving and also in the same direction. I m not sure why this happens?,
is it due to the fact that those are the same points? But in that case also they should move in opposite direction towards the shape and not in same direction.
and hence i am not somehow completing wrapping of this 2d shape as there is this black always remains on 3d in left between last two edges i.e. last face.

did u try split selection before?

Hi i am not sure what that is but i have one more problem if you can help in dm.

uv's are not visible till we press A if that option is not selected. This info is not mentioned there otherwise yes.

It is mentioned there it literally says "When you have the Sync button disabled, you can only see in the UV Editor, the faces that you have it selected in the 3D View in Edit Mode, so make sure you select all the faces you need to have it available before unchecking the Sync button, or use the 3D View to select the faces/edges/vertices you need, and tweak them in the UV Editor with the Sync button unchecked" so, it is a duplicate

ah good catch. i have not seen that somehow missed so duplicate yes

Ok I finally figured out how to do it.
Although mentioned above In UV map can't move shared vertices independently, when we keep UV Sync Selection turned off, still, to see all vertices, first we have to select all of them by pressing A while being in 3D Viewport area (the one on the left).
The entire thing was that until we press A, all vertices won't be visible on uv editing area, and after they become visible, one must keep UV selection in Vertex Selection Mode (the first option shown in the image) and then only that vertex will be able to be moved individually on his own and hence can be taken to the intended area in 2D shape where mapping is needed.

